# Windows 8 VB.net 2012 WebBrowser control IE 9 or 10

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to set the WebBrowser control in my windows form to emulate IE9 or IE10 under Windows 8.

Currently, when I use the webbrowser control on my form and load up a website it tells me:

*Your browser, Internet Explorer 7, does not support the advanced...*

However, going to that same site with just the normal IE10 browser shows the page just fine. I also double-checked the IE9 compatibility using the Developer tools within IE10 to emulate IE9 standards and that also worked.

I also tried adding my EXE file name to the registory:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\
   Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

[image]

For **64 bit** Windows 8 but that doesn't seem to have any effect on it when I run the program.

Any help would be great!

**FIXED:**

[image]

**Using vbTestProg.exe for the build EXE**

**Using the vbTestProg.vshost.exe for the Debug inside VB**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're application is a 64bit application, or compiled for AnyCPU and running on 64bit Windows, you need to set the emulation setting in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
   Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

(Without `Wow6432Node`.)  The registry location you specified is for 32bit applications running on 64bit operating systems.